# Data Extension - Combine records with same value

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

I need to combine rows with the same CONTACTKEY and instead of having two with different "Topic" value, it should have Topic set as "Both".
In the Data Extension both Email and Topic are set as Primary Key.
I'd appreciate any help.

[image: sample data]

```
SELECT
Email,
CONTACTKEY,
Topic,
Subscription_date
FROM Masterlist_Newsletter
WHERE DOI_status = 'Pending'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the following initial data:

| CK | Topic |
| --- | --- |
| User1 | MF |
| User1 | FN |
| User2 | MF |
| User3 | FN |

We just need to group the rows by the contact key, check if the user have only one `Topic` and if so, just return the existing `Topic`. If there is more than one, return `Both` (here, I'm considering `FN` and `MF` to be the only possible values).

You should find something closer to that query:

```sql
SELECT
  CK AS CK,
  CASE
    WHEN COUNT(Topic) = 1 THEN MAX(Topic)
    ELSE 'Both'
  END AS Topic
FROM
  [your_table]
GROUP BY
  CK
```

The query above returns the following data:
[image: query results]

If you want to integrate with your current query, it'll look with something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  MAX(Email) as Email,
  CONTACTKEY,
  CASE
    WHEN COUNT(Topic) = 1 THEN MAX(Topic)
    ELSE 'Both'
  END AS Topic,
  MAX(Subscription_date) as Subscription_date
FROM Masterlist_Newsletter
WHERE DOI_status = 'Pending'
GROUP BY CONTACTKEY
```

Comment: That actually helped, thank yo so much for your effort!

Comment: Glad to help! Maybe you could mark the answer as best answer? :)